# PySpark: replace string by numerical values

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following table :

```
 +----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |  _created|  _updated|                name|         description|          indication|                name|      patents_patent|
    +----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |2005-06-13|2016-08-17|           Lepirudin|Lepirudin is iden...|For the treatment...|           Lepirudin|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2017-04-27|           Cetuximab|Cetuximab is an e...|Cetuximab, used i...|           Cetuximab|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2017-06-14|        Dornase alfa|Dornase alfa is a...|Used as adjunct t...|        Dornase alfa|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2016-08-17| Denileukin diftitox|A recombinant DNA...|For treatment of ...| Denileukin diftitox|                NULL|
    |2005-06-13|2017-03-10|          Etanercept|Dimeric fusion pr...|Etanercept is ind...|          Etanercept|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2017-07-06|         Bivalirudin|Bivalirudin is a ...|For treatment of ...|         Bivalirudin|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2017-07-05|          Leuprolide|Leuprolide belong...|For treatment of ...|          Leuprolide|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2017-06-16|Peginterferon alf...|Peginterferon alf...|Peginterferon alf...|Peginterferon alf...|{"data" : [{"coun...|
    |2005-06-13|2017-06-08|           Alteplase|Human tissue plas...|For management of...|           Alteplase|                NULL|
    |2005-06-13|2016-12-08|          Sermorelin|Sermorelin acetat...|For the treatment...|          Sermorelin|                NULL|
    |2005-06-13|2016-08-17|  Interferon alfa-n1|Purified, natural...|For treatment of ...|  Interferon alfa-n1|                NULL|
```

Ideally I will need to derive 2 tables :

table_one I will filter out table where patent_patent is not NULL and replace the strings in patent-patent by 1:

```
+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |  _created|  _updated|                name|         description|          indication|                name|      patents_patent|
    +----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |2005-06-13|2016-08-17|           Lepirudin|Lepirudin is iden...|For the treatment...|           Lepirudin|1|
    |2005-06-13|2017-04-27|           Cetuximab|Cetuximab is an e...|Cetuximab, used i...|           Cetuximab|1|
    |2005-06-13|2017-06-14|        Dornase alfa|Dornase alfa is a...|Used as adjunct t...|        Dornase alfa|1|
    |2005-06-13|2017-03-10|          Etanercept|Dimeric fusion pr...|Etanercept is ind...|          Etanercept|1|
    |2005-06-13|2017-07-06|         Bivalirudin|Bivalirudin is a ...|For treatment of ...|         Bivalirudin|1|
    |2005-06-13|2017-07-05|          Leuprolide|Leuprolide belong...|For treatment of ...|          Leuprolide|1|
    |2005-06-13|2017-06-16|Peginterferon alf...|Peginterferon alf...|Peginterferon alf...|Peginterferon alf...|1|
    |
```

table_two =  filter out table where patents_patent is null and replace null by 0

```
    +----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
   |  _created|  _updated|                name|         description|          indication|                name|      patents_patent|
    +----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------
   |2005-06-13|2016-08-17| Denileukin diftitox|A recombinant DNA...|For treatment of ...| Denileukin diftitox|                0|

    |2005-06-13|2017-06-08|           Alteplase|Human tissue plas...|For management of...|           Alteplase|                0|
    |2005-06-13|2016-12-08|          Sermorelin|Sermorelin acetat...|For the treatment...|          Sermorelin|                0|
    |2005-06-13|2016-08-17|  Interferon alfa-n1|Purified, natural...|For treatment of ...|  Interferon alfa-n1|                0|
```

I tried this:

I tried this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when

data = table.where(col("patents_patent").isNull())

data = table.filter("patents_patent is not NULL")
```

The results are wrong or empty :!

```
root
 |-- _created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _updated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- indication: string (nullable = true)
 |-- patents_patent: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Can you show what you tried and where was the problem?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: What is the type of `patents_patent` can you share the schema?

Comment: are the values actually `null` or is it the string `"NULL"` as you've shown in your example?

Comment: th string is NULL as shown in the example

Comment: Ok then try: `data = table.where(col("patents_patent") == "NULL").withColumn("patents_patent", "0")` - since the column is a string column, you have to use string 0 as the replacement value.

Comment: thanks this is not working

Answer (score 0):

> > table_one I will filter out table where patent_patent is not NULL and replace the strings in patent-patent by 1:

For the first case you should do

```
data_not_null = table.filter((table['patents_patent'] != "NULL")).withColumn('patents_patent', f.lit("1"))
```

> > table_two = filter out table where patents_patent is null and replace null by 0

For the second you should be doing the following

```
data_null = table.where(f.col("patents_patent").isNull() | (table['patents_patent'] == "NULL")).withColumn('patents_patent', f.lit("0"))
```

and for these I am importing as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
```

**and of course `f.col("patents_patent")` and `table['patents_patent']` means the same**